# Linux image-viewer with multi page support for tiff

Tags: linux, image-viewer

Looking for some image-viewer to easily view multi-page tiff files, which can display float16/uint16 data, and be able to easy to display next image in directory. On windows I was using Irfanview for it.

I tried a couple of programs, but none of it was able to tick all 3 requirements.